# MaterializeCSS Open All Collapsible's by Default

Tags: materialize

Looking to open all collapsible's on page load then still allow them to be collapsible etc. Is this possible?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.collapsible').collapsible();
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `instance.open()`.

Don't pass any number in the method and all of your collapsibles will open up.

**HTML-**

```
<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS-**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var elems = document.querySelector('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems);
    instances.open();
});
```

[Collapsible - MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html)

Comment: you have to get the specific instance. e.g. var instance = instances[0]; instance.open();

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else coming here. (I just found this old post trying to work this out myself).

Actually @Cătălin Rădoi's comment is the correct one:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Get all collapsibles
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    // Initialise them
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems);
    // Get the specific collapsible - in this case the first(0)
    var instance = instances[0];
    // Pass the index of the panel you need to open  
    instance.open(0);

});
```

Tested and working [codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/QWjKRMV).

https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation recently and would like to summarize the ways to solve the problem.

**1. With Javascript only**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Initialization as presented in the docs
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible')
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, {})

    // Loop through all instances and open them
    for (var i = 0; i < instances.length; i++) {
        instances[i].open()
    }
})
```

**2. With class `active`**. If expandable type is OK, you can use it and then simply add `class="active"` to every `<li>`. Like that:

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Initialization as presented in the docs
    var elem = document.querySelector('.collapsible.expandable');
    var instance = M.Collapsible.init(elem, {
        accordion: false
    })
})
```

HTML

```
  <!-- Add expandable to ul -->
  <ul class="collapsible expandable">
    <!-- Add active to every li -->
    <li class="active">
      <div class="collapsible-header">First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <div class="collapsible-header">Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <div class="collapsible-header">Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```